# How to handle if internet connection unavailable in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, connection

In my application I want to be able to check whether the internet connection available or not.

What I want exactly:

Suppose the connection is unavailable, the app should redirect to a settings page to set "enable connection".

Here is my code to find connection availability...

```
public Map<String, String> getConnectionDetails(Context context) {
    Map<String, String> networkDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {

            networkDetails.put("Type", wifiNetwork.getTypeName());
            networkDetails.put("Sub type", wifiNetwork.getSubtypeName());
            networkDetails.put("State", wifiNetwork.getState().name());
        }

        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
            networkDetails.put("Type", mobileNetwork.getTypeName());
            networkDetails.put("Sub type", mobileNetwork.getSubtypeName());
            networkDetails.put("State", mobileNetwork.getState().name());
            if (mobileNetwork.isRoaming()) {
                networkDetails.put("Roming", "YES");
            } else {
                networkDetails.put("Roming", "NO");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        networkDetails.put("Status", e.getMessage());
    }
    return networkDetails;
}
```

And i juz toast msg like the follow

```
Map<String, String> networkDetails = networkstate.getConnectionDetails(getApplicationContext());
    if (networkDetails.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Pls give suggestion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like

```
 if (networkDetails.isEmpty()) {
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
       startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

**This will Show settings to allow configuration of wireless controls such as Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Mobile networks.**

Comment: what i have to import for wireless settings there were lot of imports suggested

Comment: @AristoMichael import android.provider.Settings;